Upvote on comments is disabled when you've already voted on the comments in Staging Ground
When you upvote a comment in the staging ground, the initial behaviour is the same as that on the main site; the icon goes from being a one colour to orange:


If you do not refresh the page, you can, like normal, revoke your upvote on the comment by clicking it again:

If, however, you refresh the page, or later navigate to the page, to ability to undo the vote is unavailable; the button is darkened (instead of orange), and if you hover over the icon, you do not get the tooltip:


This is the same behaviour as if trying to upvote a comment you posted yourself.
I would suggest this is a bug, and we should be able to revoke upvotes on comments in the SG, or at least see we were the one who upvoted it, when visiting the page later.

Seems my Google-Fu failed me, @AbdulAzizBarkat .
